# Using index number of file in directory

Tags: r

I'm using the list.files function in R. I know how to tell it to access all files in a directory, such as:

```
list.files("directory", full.names=TRUE)
```

But I don't really know how to subset the directory. If I just want list.files to list the 2nd, 5th, and 6th files in the directory, is there a way to tell list.files to only list those files? I've been thinking about whether it's possible to use the files' indices within the directory but I can't figure out how to do it. It's okay if I can only do this with consecutive files (such as 1:3) but non-consecutive would be even better.

The context of the question is that this is for a problem for a class, so I'm not worried about the files in the directory changing or being deleted.

Comment: how about `list.files()[c(1:3)]` or `list.files()[c(2,5,6)]` etc.

Comment: also, perhaps you should give more context to the problem you're going after. it's generally not a good idea to do something like "select the 2nd, 5th, and 6th" files in a directory--this code will no longer work if any of the files nearby are deleted or if any new alphabetically similar files are added.

Comment: If you have the file indices you want in a variable `id`, you can add that to the end as Michael mentioned `list.files("directory", full.names=TRUE)[id]` Especially if you are getting the value from a function argument.

Comment: Perfect! I didn't know you could subset using the c() function. You should add that as an answer so I can close the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you store the `list.files` to an object say `object` you can see that it is just an atomic vector of class `character` (nothing more nothing less!). You can subset it with the `regex` syntax for character strings (and functions that uses `regex` like `grep` or `grepl`) or just with the regular subsetting operators `[` or (most important) by combining both techniques.
For your example:

```
object[c(2,5,6)]
```

or exclude with:

```
object[-c(2,5,6)]
```

or if you want to find all names that start with the `shuttle` string with:

```
object[grepl("^shuttle", object)]
```

or with the following code if you want to find all `.csv` files:

```
object[grepl(".csv$", object)]
```

possibilities are huge.