# How do I count the number of files in a a list then use that number in R

Tags: r

I have a bunch of .csv files that I am reading into a list like this:

```
f <- list.files("conversions", full.names=TRUE)
```

Is there any way to count how many files that I am reading in and then turn that number into an object so that I can use rbind to turn the number of files into a single data frame?

I am using R Studio on a MacBook Air Pro with Yosemite

Thanks!

Comment: `length(f)` should tell you how many files are in that list. Is that what you're asking?

Comment: `numoffiles <- length(f)` ?

Comment: You shouldn't need to know the length.  Try `do.call(rbind, lapply(f, read.csv))`  Deja vu

Comment: first thing first: `list.files` does not produce a list an output but an atomic vector of class `character`.

Comment: To find out how many `.csv` files there are just have a look at [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31950322/using-index-number-of-file-in-directory/31950605#31950605) previous answer of mine. The last example I provided is exactly what you are looking for I guess.